# "over in the blink of an eye"?

Tags: idioms

What is the idiom "in the blink of an eye" in Japanese?

I want to use it to say that two years will be over in the blink of an eye or "before you even notice".

(For a detailed discussion and examples of the English idiom please see e.g. [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58385/in-the-blink-of-an-eye))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

「あっという間{ま}」 is the phrase I would suggest.

"Two years will be over in the blink of an eye." would be:

「2年{ねん}なんて、あっという間だよ。」

「2年なんて、あっという間に終{お}わるよ。」

Needless to say, 「あっという間」 literally means "while you utter 「あ」".  It is a ***very*** common and useful phrase for "in the blink of an eye".

Comment: Is it also natural Japanese if instead of なんて I say って?

Comment: That's also natural but the meaning would be a bit different. (noun)なんて conveys a contemptuous nuance to the noun.

Comment: Google has the best translation for あっという間に。

Answer (score 6):

一瞬で, 一瞬にして, etc.

Coincidentally (or not coincidentally), the 瞬 in 一瞬 means blink.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but when translating idioms I'd go for translating the colloquial meaning, not the literal meaning.

Comment: @Pandacoder Just so that I understand correctly: Is the literal translation 一瞬で not an idiom in Japanese?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer that question, but I think it might be (an idiom). To try to clarify what I meant: your translation for this specific idiom seemed to be too... literal or direct. Based on the additional criteria of "before you even notice" I would say that the other answer better fits the mental picture (that at least I have) of the idiom in English. Granted, I don't know every English variation of "in a blink of the eye", so you may have been going for something I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Pandacoder I'm the asker not the answererよ(^^)

Comment: @user213845 Ah, woops. Misread the numbers. I still think my second comment explained the meaning I was going for with my original comment so I'm ever so slightly ok with misreading. Sorry about that though.

Comment: This is not a literal translation. It is an actual phrase. It just so happens it matches English literally.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other great answers: I also heard the phrases with roughly the same meaning here and there:

- いつの間にか 「いつの間にかAがBに変わった」
- たちまちのうちに 「たちまちのうちにAが売り切れになってしまった」 (I would appreciate if a native speaker could comment if this expression is archaic or regional, heard it Kansai)

Answer (score 0):

瞬く間に（またたくまに）seems exactly the one.